# Ng-options doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I'd like to use `ng-options` for my `select` using AngularJS but it seems not working as I'd like...

```js
app.controller("LinkController", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  $http.get('/api/link').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.pages = data.pages;
  });
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="LinkController">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="page" class="control-label">Pages ({{pages.length}} pages)</label>
    <select id="page" class="form-control" ng-options="page.title for page in pages">
      <option value="">-- Please, select at least one page --</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Issue : I get no options, but `pages.length` is showing `5`

Screen ($scope.pages) :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ng-options` directive requires `ng-model`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L749) directive to be there with it.

Adding `ng-model` will fix the problem.

Comment: @tonymx227 Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model in your select or try this:

```
<div ng-controller="LinkController">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="page" class="control-label">Pages ({{pages.length}} pages)</label>
       <select id="page" class="form-control">
        <option value="">-- Please, select at least one page --</option>
        <option ng-repeat="page in pages">{{page.title}}</option>
       </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```